# How to implement paypal recurring payment in angular2

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I want to implement paypal recurring payments using angular2. I have successfully included the button for express checkout which works perfectly, but i don't have an idea of the api to use for recurring payments.

When i try to use checkout.js with this code

```
paypal.billingPlan.create(billingPlanAttributes, function (error, billingPlan) {
...
})
```

I get billingPlan is not defined. Has anybody done this successfully, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do Recurring payment in REST API with Paypal is that you are required to have an active billing plans.

The orders are ;

1. Create Billing Plans
2. Update Billing Plans to Active
3. Call Billing Agreement.

In your cases, you need an active billing plans before calling the billing agreement. PayPal use the billing plans to define the billing agreement between buyer and seller.

Comment: But does checkout.js have the ability to handle billing?